# How can users see the comments in a PowerPoint file via the graph-api Preview URL?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, powerpoint, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

We are using Graph API to display our on-premises sharepoint files within a public facing web app. The users of the web app have complained that comments in powerpoint files are important and they cannot see these via our app (we use graph's preview url to display the file to them.)

Short of asking them to download a copy of the file to open in PowerPoint themselves (our stake holders don't want users to be able to download copies of our files) is there any way this is possible via the viewer?

If we use the webUrl property from graph-api, this opens the file on sharepoint in the Office 365 PowerPoint web app, which allows for viewing slideshow comments, but this is not going to work for users as they do not have accounts for our on premises sharepoint so will be prompted to log into our sharepoint site at this point (we do not want them to have accounts here.)

Current code (simplified) is:

```
<a href='#' onclick="LoadFilePreview('{sharepoint-item-id-goes-here}')>Click here to view the slideshow</a>
```

And the js:

```
    function LoadFilePreview(itemId) {
        var auth = $("#authToken").val();
        var graphUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/" + siteId + "/drive/items/" + itemId + "/preview";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: graphUrl,
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + auth },
            accept: "application/json"
        }).done(function (data) {
            window.open(data.getUrl);
        }).fail(function (e) {
            ajaxFailed(e.status, LoadFilePreview, itemId);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that we can't call `POST /drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/preview` without a signed in user.

Based on [driveItem: preview Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-preview?view=graph-rest-1.0#permissions), Application permission(without user) is not supported.
[image]

You can post your idea on [Microsoft Graph User Voice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) to get attention of the product group.